# How to convert text to timestamp with adjusted format?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that one of its column contains timestamp.

This column defined as text field.

The timestamp format is as follow:

```
"2021-01-05T:12:29:30"
"2021-05-15T:15:23:00"
```

How can I convert this text field to timestamp using `TO_TIMESTAMP` function ?

Comment: With `convert` you mean you want to change the data type of the column using `ALTER TABLE`?

Comment: to view the content with select TO_TIMESTAMP(....)

Comment: Well, changing the column's type would be the wise thing to do. But it's unclear to me, what output you are looking for then.

Comment: After I will convert to timestamp, I can use other function (as group by 'day'....)

Comment: Then it would be even better to fix your data model and change the column's type to `timestamp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TO_TIMESTAMP` with a format

```
to_timestamp(you_text_column,'YYYY-MM-DDT:hh24:mi:ss') as your_timestamp
```

But somehow that odd format you have can also be type casted to a timestamp

```
select '2021-01-05T:12:29:30'::timestamp
```

I'm calling it odd because it's not even in an [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.
Since it has that extra `:`

Comment: I'm getting null values...

Comment: It works in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f7842b57f3dd0fa35763f5cec1e0bf51). Could you try to reproduce your null result in the fiddle? Btw, use single quotes for string literals.